# "Visto", quando significa "considerato", deve concordare con il sostantivo?

Tags: agreement

Quest'utilizzo mi sembra aggettivale e quindi dev'esserci concordanza tra "visto" e il sostantivo. Consultando due dizionari ho trovato questi esempi:

> **viste** le difficoltà dell'impresa, proporrei di rinunciarvi
>
> **vista** la loro età, ...

Finora tutto bene, ma leggendo una notizia mi sono imbattuto nella seguente frase:

> «...In Ue ci sono troppi egoismi nazionali anche per colpa dei populismi che avvelenano l'Europa», e non solo, **visto** le bordate lanciate alla Casa Bianca.

Si tratta di un errore, oppure si ritiene accettabile (almeno in certi casi) usare "visto" come una sorta di aggettivo invariabile?

Comment: L'ultimo esempio mi suona veramente come il gessetto sulla lavagna...

Comment: Direi che si tratta di un errore…

Comment: Lo considererei un errore "da lingua parlata".

Comment: Qualcuno può scrivere una risposta?

Comment: Se ne parla [qui](http://www.achyra.org/cruscate/viewtopic.php?t=4944).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In questa [voce del vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/visto) puoi vedere che, in questo tipo di costruzioni, "visto" è effettivamente adoperato come aggettivo e, per questa ragione, deve concordare con il sostantivo a cui si riferisce in genere e in numero. La spiegazione del vocabolario Treccani che fa riferimento a questo utilizzo di "visto" è quella che comincia così:

> In costruzioni assol., nelle quali equivale a «avendo visto, avendo considerato» o «dal momento che, tenuto conto che»

Poi il Treccani propone questi esempi nei quali si può osservare tale concordanza:

> - ***viste*** le difficoltà dell’impresa, proporrei di rinunciarvi
> - *il giovane, **vista** la mala parata, se la diede a gambe*
> - ***visto*** che tutti tacciono, parlerò io.

Comment: Immagino che l'errore provenga dalla confusione tra questo uso aggettivale di "visto" e l'espressione "avendo visto" a cui, in parole del Treccani, equivale. Per esempio, "viste le difficoltà dell’impresa" equivale a "avendo visto le difficoltà dell’impresa" (uso verbale di "vedere").

Comment: Tuttavia, quando si adopera "visto" come participio in un tempo verbale composto con l'ausiliare "avere", come appunto si vede della spiegazione del vocabolario Treccani («avendo visto, avendo considerato»), "visto" può anche significare "considerato".

Comment: In questo caso, la [grammatica Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/concordanza_%28La-grammatica-italiana%29/) spiega: «in presenza di un participio passato seguito da un complemento oggetto, il participio è di solito al maschile singolare, indipendentemente dal genere e dal numero del complemento oggetto». Cioè, in italiano moderno, di solito si direbbe, per esempio, "avendo visto le difficoltà dell’impresa".

Comment: Comunque, lo stesso articolo della grammatica Treccani anche afferma: «è sempre più rara, anche se non sbagliata, la concordanza con il complemento oggetto, normale fino a un secolo fa».

Comment: Lo si può trovare, per esempio, in un [testo](https://books.google.es/books?id=nIkHAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA223&lpg=PA223&dq=%22avendo+viste+le%22+Torquato+Tasso&source=bl&ots=nPj6RdJDRY&sig=AeDHLPT_iL4tiZKVa9uswZQVBDA&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiBnbni7vPYAhWDDcAKHXx5BRYQ6AEIFjAE#v=onepage&q=%22avendo%20viste%20le%22%20Torquato%20Tasso&f=false) di [Torquato Tasso](http://www.viv-it.org/autori-opere/autori/torquato-tasso): «Vide dunque quante potevano essere le differenze essenziali della poesia, ed **avendo viste le differenze**, vide in conseguenza quante potevano essere le sue spezie, perché...»